# Add a file field to a block

Tags: entities, blocks

I have a problem concerning the blocks in drupal.

I need to create a block that has additional fields, image and files, I am currently using the add block feature in Home » Administration » Structure and I just need to add two fields there so I can upload pdf's and images.

I was thinking that there must be a way to add those fields from the admin panel, without programming it by hand or installing modules? Is it possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

Blocks aren't entities in Drupal 7, so there's no real way to add fields to them.

If you want fields on blocks, then take a look at the awesome [Bean](http://www.drupal.org/project/bean) module.

> Beans were driven by the API first. This means that you can create
>   block types (bean types) all in a plugin class turning off the UI. The
>   entire configuration in code. No worry about feature reverts.

Comment: Well that answers my question, thanks:) i am installing the module now.